# SKScene's update UIKit equivalent

Tags: function, swift, uikit

Is there a function in `UIKit` which can be overriden equivalent to `SKScene`'s update?

If not, how to achieve having my function executing on every step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent function as `SKScene's` update.

But there is similar way of achieving the intended function:

- `CADisplayLink`, is the closest for such function. You can initialize it something like:

  ```
  CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animate)];
  [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  ```

animate is your own function that will be called. Remember to call [displayLink invalidate] when you are finished.

- `drawRect:(CGRect)rect`, is being called every time the view is being redraw and can also being triggered by calling `setNeedsDisplay`.
- `NSTimer`, is another way to do so. But, try not to use if your function is to animate as the timing function (fps) of `NSTimer` is not as accurate as **CA**